# How to make a custom listview clickable

Tags: java, android, custom-lists

I'm having trouble making a listview item clickable. I've tried if statments, onclicklisteners and I'm still not having any success, does anyone know how to do this? I also have another class to get the strings, but I don't think it is needed. If you could help me out with this, I would appreciate it! Thanks!Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{

private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog = null; 
private ArrayList<Order> m_orders = null;
private OrderAdapter m_adapter;
private Runnable viewOrders;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
    this.m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, R.layout.row, m_orders);
    setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);

    viewOrders = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getOrders();
        }
    };
    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();
    m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,    
          "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);
}
private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(m_orders != null && m_orders.size() > 0){
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for(int i=0;i<m_orders.size();i++)
            m_adapter.add(m_orders.get(i));
        }
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
private void getOrders(){
      try{
          m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
          Order o1 = new Order();
          o1.setOrderName("Item 1");
          o1.setOrderStatus("2012");
          o1.setorderpic(R.drawable.bulb);
          Order o2 = new Order();
          o2.setOrderName("Item 2");
          o2.setOrderStatus("Completed");
          o2.setorderpic(R.drawable.bulb);
          m_orders.add(o1);
          m_orders.add(o2);
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          Log.i("ARRAY", ""+ m_orders.size());
        } catch (Exception e) { 
          Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
        }
        runOnUiThread(returnRes);
    }
private class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {

    private ArrayList<Order> items;

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Order> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }
            Order o = items.get(position);
            if (o != null) {
                    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                    TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
                    ImageView ct = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                    if (tt != null) {
                          tt.setText("Name: "+o.getOrderName());                            }
                    if(bt != null){
                          bt.setText("Status: "+ o.getOrderStatus());
                    }
                    if(ct !=null){
                        ct.setImageResource(o.getorderpic());
                    }
            }
            return v;
    }
```

}

Comment: Do you want the entire listview to be clickable or each item in the listview?

Comment: Each item in the listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use view's OnClickListener in getView() of your custom adapter

```
v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v) {

        // do something on click    
        }

    });
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Comment: This probably isn't the best way to do it, generally you would use an `OnItemClickListener` attached to the listview. This will be called when ever any item is clicked. Redoing an `OnClickListener` is going to be expensive inside the adapter.

Comment: @draksia feel free to edit the answer.Put a edit as heading and your suggestion if you have better suggestion

Comment: In this case alexei burmistrov answer is actually the correct one. The reason for not doing it in the getView() method is that this is called frequently when the a view is being shown.

Answer (score 2):

You should override ListActivity's onListItemClick method. This is what ListActivity is made for.

[onListItemClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29)

Comment: If you are using ListActivity this is the correct way to do this.